# Netlogo: asking "up to a maximum number"

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to ask up to a certain number of patches? For example, ask up to 100 patches but there are only 50 available, so the action takes on this 50 patches. Thanks.

Comment: Nicolas's answer is the most elegant way to do this. An alternative answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697025/ask-up-to-n-of-turtles/35701692#35701692. I'm not marking as duplicate question as both answers are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this at the moment would be something like:

```
to-report at-most [n agents]
  report ifelse-value (n <= count agents) [ agents ] [ n-of n agents ]
end
```

You can then say `ask at-most 100 patches [ ... ]` and you will get what you want.

Note that this doesn't work if there is a chance that your variable contains `nobody` instead of an agentset. In that case, you can convert `nobody` to an agentset using `patch-set`, `turtle-set` or `link-set`, depending on the type of agent you expect it to contain. For example:

```
ask one-of turtle-set other turtles-here [ ... ]
```

Note that the need to jump through all these hoops might disappear in the near future. There is currently an open proposal to add a primitive to NetLogo for handling these cases: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1594.

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with `to-report` command. What does `n` and `agents` mean in this context and where do I input their values?

Comment: The `n` and `agents` aren't because this is a `to-report`. `to-report` means instead of doing something (like a `to` block), this code sends back a number or agentset or whatever. The `n` and `agents` are variables that are being passed to the command block with an arbitrary name that is then used within the command block.